# what is the best way to make a arp responder in sdn?

Tags: openstack, arp, sdn, openstack-neutron

There are mainly two methods, one is to use pre-configurated flows, which is similar to neutron's arp responder. The other is like https://github.com/mbredel/floodlight-proxyarp, send out the arp packet by the controller. I want to know witch way is better and why.

Answer (score 0):

Before my opinion, i want to write two notes:

In SDN World, preconfigurated flows are called "proactive" flows. Flows that are set when a request is come are called reactive flows.

ARP requests are important for security issues (like arp poisining).

When we come to your question, first method could be chosed, because controller's job is critical in the SDN world, second method is an extra job for controller. But for experimental issues of course it could be chosed.

In fact, there is another method to reduce controller's job, you can set flows to the openflow switch, to response arp requests directly. This solution also shows that arp traffic is very important for controller's performance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The first method may add a lot of flows when there is so many vms in one subnet, how to solve that?